# Thread Looping and not Going Outside of Block

Tags: android, multithreading, progress-bar

I have a method here which loads data from Firestore and populates in My View. Here i Am trying to use a progressbar. I kept the logic for progress inside my Thread but it seems like something is wrong here as it wont come out of loop. This code is working fine in other place.
pStatus is declared as of type int. Please help as m stuck on it since whole day

```
private void loadDataFromFirebase() {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             final Handler handler2 = new Handler();
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (pStatus <= 100) {
                        handler2.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Log.e("Thread","Running Thread Load Data");
                                Log.e("Thread",String.valueOf(pStatus));
                                progressBar.setProgress(pStatus);
                                if(pStatus==100){
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }).start();

            firebaseFirestore.collection("Merchant").document(id)
                    .get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
    
                    Log.e("Thread","Query");
                    Map<String, Object> temp = documentSnapshot.getData();
                    Map<String, Object> temp2 = (Map<String, Object>) temp.get("Items");
                    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> it = temp2.entrySet().iterator();
                    while (it.hasNext()) {
                        Map.Entry<String, Object> entry = it.next();
                        System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
                        String Item_name = entry.getKey();
                        Map<String, String> items = new HashMap<>();
                        items = (Map<String, String>) entry.getValue();
                        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> it2 = items.entrySet().iterator();
                        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                        String a = "";
                        String b = "";
                        String c = "";
                        String d = "";
                        while (it2.hasNext()) {
                            Map.Entry<String, String> entry2 = it2.next();
                            System.out.println("Key = " + entry2.getKey() +
                                    ", Value = " + entry2.getValue());
                            if (entry2.getKey().equals("Name")) {
                                a = entry2.getValue();
                            } else if (entry2.getKey().equals("Metric")) {
                                b = entry2.getValue();
                            } else if (entry2.getKey().equals("Price")) {
                                c = entry2.getValue();
                            } else if (entry2.getKey().equals("Quantity")) {
                                d = entry2.getValue();
                            }
                        }
                        list.add(a);
                        list.add(b);
                        list.add(c);
                        list.add(d);
                        System.out.println(list);
                        OrderItemModel order = new OrderItemModel(list.get(0), list.get(1),
                                Integer.parseInt(list.get(2)), Integer.parseInt(list.get(3)));
                        orderItemModelArrayList.add(order);
                    }
                    adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(OrderItemList.this, orderItemModelArrayList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    pStatus=pStatus+100;
    
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the thread you handle data is the main thread(UI thread),you can print a log to verify this. But your intention is to put it in the child thread.
Below is my logic:

```
private static final int HANDLE_DATA = 1;
private Handler uiHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                List<String> data = msg.obj;
                // set adapter data and refresh recyclerview
                ...
                progressBar.setViesibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
}
private HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("worker_thread");
private Handler handler = new Handler(thread.getLooper()) {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                if (msg.what == HANDLE_DATA) {
                    DocumentsSnapShot data = (DocumentsSnapShot)msg.obj;
                    // handle data
                    ...
                    Message msg = uiHandler.obtainMessage(0, handleResultData);
                    uiHandler.postMsg(msg);
                }
            }
        };

public void onCreate() {
  ...
  thread.start();
  ...
}

private void loadDataFromFirebase() {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    firebaseFirestore.collection("Merchant").document(id)
                .get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(HANDLE_DATA, documentSnapshot);
                handler.postMessage(msg);
            }
        }
}
```

..